# Can not start SQL Server, model db in RESTORING state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Quick run down:

First problem started when sysadmin received error that `model` is recovering.

Sometime later vendor tried to do some upgrades to the database. When they restarted SQL Server it failed to start.

Looking at error log. I found the following error

> Error The database 'model' is marked RESTORING and is in a state that
> does not allow recovery to be run. Error: 927, Severity: 14, State: 2.
> Database 'model' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.
> Could not create tempdb. You may not have enough disk space available.
> Free additional disk space by deleting other files on the tempdb drive
> and then restart SQL Server. Check for additional errors in the event
> log that may indicate why the tempdb files could not be initialized.

after searching around on the web found [this article on MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20160227001650/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/karthick_pk/archive/2010/11/26/the-database-model-is-marked-restoring-and-is-in-a-state-that-does-not-allow-recovery-to-be-run.aspx)

using steps from article started sql server using `Sqlservr.exe -sInstanceName -T3608 -c -f -T3609` when i tried to run `Use tempdb` got error message. Following advice from article I copied tempdb.mdf and templog.ldf from another server.

Now I get the following error:

> Starting up database 'tempdb'. Error: 3456, Severity: 21, State: 1.
> Could not redo log record (19:45:366), for transaction ID (0:0), on
> page (1:16), database 'tempdb' (database ID 2). Page: LSN = (18:72:8),
> type = 1. Log: OpCode = 18, context 2, PrevPageLSN: (19:45:287).
> Restore from a backup of the database, or repair the database.

Comment: the bigger question you should ask is what the vendor did that was messing with model and tempdb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying large number of alternative steps was able to fix the problem and get the database started.

Here are the steps I took:

- On another SQL Server 2008 R2, I moved my `model` and `temp` db files to same location as on my problem server. Refer to this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx
- Replaced model and tempdb .mdf and .ldf files on my problem server. Old files I saved in another directory just incase.
- Tried to start the SQL Server services, verified error message

> The database 'model' is marked RESTORING and is in a state that does
>   not allow recovery to be run. Error: 927, Severity: 14, State: 2.
>   Database 'model' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.
>   Could not create tempdb. You may not have enough disk space available.
>   Free additional disk space by deleting other files on the tempdb drive
>   and then restart SQL Server. Check for additional errors in the event
>   log that may indicate why the tempdb files could not be initialized.

After that I opened two separate Command Prompt windows.

Below to make it easier I call first command prompt windows CPA, and second one CPB.

- in CPA run `Sqlservr.exe -sInstanceName -T3608 -c -f -T3609` (note: I had to navigate to binary location) don't forget to replace `InstanceName` with yours
- - `-T3608` only starts `master` [Trace Flags documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- - `-T3609` skips creation of `tempdb`
- in CPB run `SQLCMD -E -SADMIN:Servername\InstanceName` replace with your ServerName\InstanceName. [Using a Dedicated Administrator Connection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- in CPB run `sp_detach_db 'model'` then `go`
- in CPB run the following code, just replace with your file location.

---

```
CREATE DATABASE [model] ON
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.R2\MSSQL\DATA\model.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.R2\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf' ) FOR ATTACH
go
```

- in CPA you should see `Starting 'MODEL'` messsage
- in CPA hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> that will show message if you want to exit hit <kbd>Y</kbd>

Using SQL Server Configuration Manager or Services page start SQL Server service.

After I was able to connect using SSMS.